# Hide Some Nested Attribues of Pivot Table Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel 8. I have a pivot table with four columns:

1. user_id
2. operator_id
3. discount
4. local_discount

I have defined two relations, one for my project and one for API

```
public function operators(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Operator::class,'reseller_rates','user_id','operator_id')->withPivot(['discount','local_discount']);
}

public function api_operators(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Operator::class,'reseller_rates','user_id','operator_id')->as('rates')->withPivot(['discount','local_discount']);
}
```

But it gives all four columns of pivot table when I use this relation

```
$operators = $user['api_operators']
```

I know I can hide some columns of operators table using laravel's makeHidden method

```
$operators->makeHidden(['discount','local_discount']);
```

But how can I hide user_id and operator_id which is returned with pivot data. Is there any way to use makeHidden with nested attributes of pivot table to hide user_id and operator_id? Or any other better way to achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide these columns from your api, I would instead go for api resources:
[https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Comment: I have a work around. 
       foreach ($operators as $key => $operator){
            unset($operators[$key]['rates']['user_id']);
            unset($operators[$key]['rates']['operator_id']);
        } 
but Isn't there a better solution than this?

Comment: @ndberg what if I don't have followed eloquent resources this is only your solution?